# Reading binary magnetic field with Matlab

Tags: matlab, binary, field

I am trying to read some magnetic fields using Matlab. To do so, I am using Windows XP OS and I am sending the command to continuos reading from the device using Putty. While Putty its running and saving the log file I am reading this log file on Matlab. The Device is a HMR2300. 
When I am reading this using ASCII format I am not facing any problems at all. However, I need to collect this data in binary and this is the problem. 
The output string is 7 bytes long "Xh|Xl|Yh|Yl|Zh|Zl|" Xh = Signed Byte, X axis - Xl= Low byte, X axis.

Since I have four devices, I am collecting all data inside of a while loop with this code:

```
%*****% Reading from Device 01
[D1, N] = fread(FidMag1, 7);
while (true)
  MagData1 = [MagData1, D1'];
  CRLF1    = find(MagData1 == 13);
  CRLF1 = [0, CRLF1]';
  if (CRLF1(end) ~= 7)
    MagData1(1:CRLF1(end))=[];
    [D1, N] = fread(FidMag1, 7);
  else
    break;
  end
end
ttt = clock();
TimeStamp1(Count) = ttt(6) + ttt(5)*60 + ttt(4)*3600;
NoCalMagX1(Count) = int16(typecast(uint8(MagData1(1)), 'int8')) * int16(256) + (MagData1(2));
NoCalMagY1(Count) = int16(typecast(uint8(MagData1(3)), 'int8')) * int16(256) + (MagData1(4));
NoCalMagZ1(Count) = int16(typecast(uint8(MagData1(5)), 'int8')) * int16(256) + (MagData1(6));
MagData1(1:CRLF1(end))=[];
```

So, after that I am reading in a row devices 2, 3, and 4.

This is my result:
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urfgn.jpg)

You can see roughly that before and after 200 sec I am having a delay to collect the data and this is what I need to solve. Usually when my field starts to change, I start to receive a delay and I don't know how to solve it.

I've tried to do a different approach with my code however this is just worst then the first one:

```
%*****% Reading from Device 01
if (SYNC_1)
    [D1, countB] = fread(FidMag1, 7-BIB_1);
    if (countB ~= 7)
        for a=1:countB
            temp(BIB_1+a) = D1(a); 
        end
    end
    if (flag_temp)
        flag_temp = 0;
    else if(find(D1 == 13) == 7)
            for a=1:countB
               temp(a) = D1(a); 
            end
        end
    end
    BIB_1 = BIB_1 + countB;
    if(BIB_1 == 7)
            if  (find(temp == 13) == 7)
                ttt = clock();
                TimeStamp1(Count_1) = ttt(6) + ttt(5)*60 + ttt(4)*3600;
                NoCalMagX1(Count_1) = int16(typecast(uint8(temp(1)), 'int8')) * int16(256) + (temp(2));
                NoCalMagY1(Count_1) = int16(typecast(uint8(temp(3)), 'int8')) * int16(256) + (temp(4));
                NoCalMagZ1(Count_1) = int16(typecast(uint8(temp(5)), 'int8')) * int16(256) + (temp(6));
                fprintf('SENSOR B\nX:%.0f  Y:%.0f  Z:%.0f\n\n', NoCalMagX1(Count_1), NoCalMagY1(Count_1), NoCalMagZ1(Count_1));
                Count_1 = Count_1 + 1;
            else
                SYNC_1 = 0;
            end
            BIB_1 = 0;
    end
end 
if (~SYNC_1)
    [D1, countB] = fread(FidMag1, 7-BIB_1);
    BIB_1 = BIB_1 + countB;
    if (BIB_1 > 0)
        index = find (D1 == 13);
        if(index)
            BIB_1 = 7 - index(end);
            if(BIB_1 == 0)
                flag_temp = 1;
                for a=(BIB_1+1):7
                 temp(a-BIB_1) = D1(a); 
                end
            else
                for a=(index+1):countB
                 temp(aux) = D1(a);
                 aux = aux + 1;
                end
            end
            aux = 1; %temp index
            SYNC_1 = 1;
        else
            SYNC_1 = 0;
            BIB_1 = 0;
        end
    end
end
```

Results:
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWE2d.jpg)

Do you guys have any idea how can I solve this? To collect data using ascii my approach its similar and I don't have any problems. Also when I am reading from just one device using the first code I don't have any problems too. I am just lost in how to solve that.

Comment: Are you sure it's matlab's fault? Shouldn't the logfile be what it is, regardless of what you read it with? Or maybe I misunderstand.

Comment: Hi Andras, thanks for your answer. I am 100% that  that is a delay reading the log file. This image is the data collection using the ascii mode and using this method we aren't facing anu problem. Check the image here: http://s18.postimg.org/kgq0nb815/hallway_mag_2.jpg